# Is it safe to export Firestore data multiple times to the same storage folder? Could the overwrite break the exported data?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

Here is how I'm exporting my Firestore data:

```
import { today } from "@utils/dates/today";
import * as admin from "firebase-admin";

admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(
    MY_SERVICE_ACCOUNT as admin.ServiceAccount
)});

const client = new admin.firestore.v1.FirestoreAdminClient();
const BUCKET = "gs://MY_PROJECT_ID.appspot.com/firestore-backup";
const PROJECT_ID = "MY_PROJECT_ID";
const DB_NAME = client.databasePath(PROJECT_ID, "(default)");

export const backupData = async () : Promise<void> => {

  const todayDate = today();  // THIS IS YYYY-MM-DD STRING
  // const hashId = generateId().slice(0,5);

  const responses = await client.exportDocuments({
    name: DB_NAME,
    outputUriPrefix: `${BUCKET}/${todayDate}`,
    collectionIds: []
  });

  const response = responses[0];
  console.log(`Operation Name: ${response['name']}`);

  return;
};
```

You see I'm exporting to the following path:

```
/firestore-backup/YYYY-MM-DD/
```

If I'm going to backup multiple times over the same day, can I use same date folder? Is it safe to do it? Or should I add a `hash` to the folder name to avoid overwriting the previous export?

**PS:** The overwrite on a single day is not a problem. I just don't want to break the exported data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you go to the bucket and check the exports you'll see that the files exported seem to follow the same pattern every time. If we were to rely only on the write/update semantics of Cloud Storage, whenever there's a write to a location where a file already exists it is overwritten. Therefore, at first it doesn't seem it would cause data corruption.

However, the assumption above relies on the internal behavior of the export operations, which may be subject to future change (let aside that I can't even guarantee them as of now). Therefore, the best practice would be appending a hash to the folder name to prevent any unexpected behavior.

As an additional sidenote, it's worth mentioning that exports could incur in huge costs depending on the size of your Firestore data.